# how can i resize a pdf with js

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I am working on the responsive design and I want the scale of the pdf to vary depending on the size of the screen, how can I change it since with the current code the pdf has a fixed width

```
if (pageNumber >= 1 && pageNumber <= doc._pdfInfo.numPages) {

    // Fetch the page
    const page = await doc.getPage(pageNumber);

    // Set the viewport
    const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1 });

    // Set the canvas dimensions to the PDF page dimensions
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    // Render the PDF page into the canvas context
    return await page.render({
        canvasContext: context,
        viewport: viewport
    }).promise;

} else {
    console.log("Please specify a valid page number");
}
```

Comment: can you provide more details and code?

Comment: sure, what I don't understand is how to change const viewport = page.getViewport ({scale: 1});
because this scale works well for me until I get to a screen size of 622px, what I want is that in a screen size smaller than 622px the scale drops to 0.75

Comment: you can check window.innerWidth to detect the width. If it is less than 662px then set the scale 0.75 else set the scale 1.

Comment: How can I put that condition in code form, sorry I'm new to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code.

```
if (pageNumber >= 1 && pageNumber <= doc._pdfInfo.numPages) {
    
        // Fetch the page
        const page = await doc.getPage(pageNumber);
    
        // Set the viewport
         let scale;
        if(window.innerWidth < 662px) {
           scale = 0.75
        } else {
           scale = 1
        }
        const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale });
    
        // Set the canvas dimensions to the PDF page dimensions
        const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
    
        // Render the PDF page into the canvas context
        return await page.render({
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport
        }).promise;
    
    } else {
        console.log("Please specify a valid page number");
    }
```